# Parent refs are null when method is being called by child component - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to call a method from a parent component inside of a child component in React. This is the code of my parent component:

```
import Video from 'Video/Video';

class CaseHeader extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Bind functions
    this.videoComponentDidMount = this.videoComponentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

  videoComponentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.caseheader);
  }

  render() {
    let video = null;

    if (this.props.caseData.title) {
      video = <Video videoComponentDidMount={this.videoComponentDidMount} />;
    }

    return(
      <div styleName="CaseHeader" ref={caseheader => this.caseheader = caseheader}>
        {video}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default CaseHeader;
```

So what I'm trying to do is this: my `CaseHeader` component is rendering another component called `Video`. I need to wait for this component to finish rendering to get his height. So I'm passing a method to the `Video` which will be called in the `componentDidMount` method. When the method is called I know the `Video` component is rendered and I can get its offsetHeight. This is the code of the `Video` component:

```
class Video extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.videoComponentDidMount();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div styleName="Video" ref={video => this.video = video}></div>
    );
  }

}

export default Video;
```

So I expect the `console.log(this.caseheader)` statement to log the DOM element of the `CaseHeader`. The problem is this doesn't happen, `null` gets logged instead.

When I add a the following code the CaseHeader component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.caseheader);
}
```

The `componentDidMount` method logs the right value but the `videoComponentDidMount` method doesn't. This is a screenshot of what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr0ti.jpg

So my question is: How can I make parent refs (`this.caseheader` in this case) defined when the function is being called from a child component?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Thanks to the help here I solved this issue by using the state of the `CaseHeader`. What I did was update the constructor and added one method:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // Set initial state
  this.state = {
    videoIsActive: false
  };

  // Bind functions
  this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind(this);
}

handleStateChange(state) {
  this.setState(state);
}
```

So here I keep track off the video is active. I also pass the `handleStateChange` method to the `Video` component:

`video = <Video updateParentState={this.handleStateChange} />;`

In the `Video` component I added the following:

`this.props.updateParentState({videoIsActive: true});`

This calls the following code in the `CaseHeader`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.videoIsActive) {
    this.setCaseheaderBackgroundHeight();
  }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Could it be because the ref callback is defined as an inline function meaning called first with null? See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats

Comment: How would I set this up another way?

Comment: Why don't you set that offsetHeight of Video using setState in the caseHeader? So in the componentDidMount of Video class pass the offsetHeight value to the parent Component and in the CaseHeader videoComponentDidMount use that value to set state. Then access the offsetHeight property by calling this.state.offsetHeight?

Comment: add null check to your `ref` function in `CaseHeader` and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks @Trinu I was just going the wrong direction with this one. Using the state solved my issues immediately.

Comment: @DavidWorldpeace cool np

Comment: @DavidWorldpeace I see you solved the issue but just to answer you comment, we have been using [class instance field with an arrow function](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/#way-4-class-instance-field-with-an-arrow-function-good-es8). You could also bind the ref setter function in the constructor like you did with the `handleStateChange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set that offsetHeight of Video using setState in the caseHeader? So in the componentDidMount of Video class pass the offsetHeight value to the parent Component and in the CaseHeader videoComponentDidMount use that value to set state. Then access the offsetHeight property by calling this.state.offsetHeight?